# How to calculate a faster days-in-month weighted average

Tags: r, data.table

It is common that energy meters don't start and end on the beginning and end of a month but overlap unevenly with the calendar. I'm trying to use weighted average logic to line up these read dates and calculate a single month value. I've attached my code example that builds a similar dataset to what I'm working with. Each row is an individual energy meter. Every 3 columns represents a start date and end date, and the value of energy used for that time period.

I've been working on hundreds of thousands of rows and this process takes over twenty minutes. I'd love to be able to use `data.table` but I'm too new to it and I'm unsure how to get the `seq.Date` to work given the column structure of the data.

```
# Making the Fake Dataset
set.seed(123)
fake_rows = 10
{
  testdata <- replicate(fake_rows, {
    start_it <- as.Date('2019/01/01') + sample(-20:20, 1, T)
    track <- start <- end <- value <- c()
    for(i in 1:12){
      a <- seq.Date(start_it, length.out = sample(28:34,1), by="day")
      start[i] <- a[1]
      end[i] <- start_it <- a[length(a)]
      value[i] <- sample(1:200,1)
      track <- c(track, start[i], end[i], value[i])
    }
    return(track)
  })

  testdata <- as.data.frame(t(testdata)) 

  month_labels <- c(paste0("0",1:9), "10","11","12")
  start_dates <- sapply(month_labels, function(x) paste0("Start_Date_",x))
  end_dates <- sapply(month_labels, function(x) paste0("End_Date_",x))
  values <- sapply(month_labels, function(x) paste0("Value_",x))

  colnames(testdata) <- c(rbind(start_dates,end_dates,values))

  # replace columns with the dates
  for(i in c(start_dates, end_dates)){
    testdata[,i] <- as.Date(testdata[,i], origin = "1970-01-01")
  }

  testdata[2, 7:36] <- NA # some are missing dates and values
}
```

`testdata`

```
#   Start_Date_01 End_Date_01 Value_01 Start_Date_02 End_Date_02 Value_02
#1     2019-01-11  2019-02-13      179    2019-02-13  2019-03-17      195
#2     2018-12-20  2019-01-21      164    2019-01-21  2019-02-22       81
#3     2019-01-05  2019-02-02       69    2019-02-02  2019-03-04       63
#4     2018-12-28  2019-01-29       50    2019-01-29  2019-02-25       34
#5     2019-01-15  2019-02-16      199    2019-02-16  2019-03-17      151
#6     2019-01-15  2019-02-16       94    2019-02-16  2019-03-21       24
#7     2019-01-05  2019-02-07       54    2019-02-07  2019-03-07      137
#8     2019-01-16  2019-02-15      108    2019-02-15  2019-03-19      177
#9     2018-12-25  2019-01-25       16    2019-01-25  2019-02-27      125
#10    2019-01-09  2019-02-07       10    2019-02-07  2019-03-10       54
```

I've gone with the data.frame approach below:

```
library(data.table)
# for each row, determine what monthly values would be
output <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(testdata), ncol = 12)
month_cols <- as.character(1:12)

for(i in 1:nrow(testdata)){
  x <- y <- vector("list", 12)

  for(j in 1:12){
    if(!is.na(testdata[i, start_dates[j]])){
      # get the counts of days in each month within the meter read period
      x[[j]] <- table(month(seq.Date(testdata[i, start_dates[j]], testdata[i, end_dates[j]], "day")))
      # multiply the meter read value by days in each month (the numerator of a day wtd avg)
      y[[j]] <- testdata[i, values[j]] * x[[j]]      
    }
    months <- names(unlist(y))
    # day weighted average  = Σ(value x Days) / Σ(Days)
    final <- tapply(unlist(y), months, sum) / tapply(unlist(x), months, sum) 
    output[i,] <- final[match(month_cols, names(final))] # ordered in the case of missing months
  }
}
```

`output`

Where the rows are the rows of the original data set, and the columns represent an estimated value for month January through month February, no specific year attached since I'm day-weighting all values across months regardless of year.

```
#         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]     [,7]      [,8]       [,9]    [,10]     [,11]     [,12]
# [1,] 140.77778 187.82759 127.03125  46.16129  28.50000  81.25806 125.8750  91.00000  91.516129 120.1250 108.80645  32.87500
# [2,] 135.46875  81.00000        NA        NA        NA        NA       NA        NA         NA       NA        NA 164.00000
# [3,]  80.61290  63.41379  92.75000  91.77419  39.96970  45.74194  87.6875  20.87500 100.838710 196.4375  86.00000 154.43750
# [4,]  48.50000  31.10345  30.81250 130.35484 128.43750  48.70968 117.8125  27.81250  55.322581 137.0312 123.38710 145.65714
# [5,] 142.03571 177.48276 137.40625 106.48387 102.53125 116.00000  86.0000 102.25000 112.032258 153.4375 183.29032  96.50000
# [6,]  88.34286  62.62069  52.53125 126.87097 132.62500 128.19355 157.9688 103.43750   9.612903  30.6250  93.67742 131.09375
# [7,]  62.91429 116.96552  67.46875  72.83871 102.25000 171.32258 178.5000 112.50000  38.645161 131.0000 127.22581  96.43750
# [8,]  86.08696 141.31034 129.06250  35.77419  97.00000 122.93548 146.3125 128.18750 151.161290 199.1250 172.90323  74.75000
# [9,]  39.84375 119.13793  70.00000 180.64516  85.12500  49.64516 116.5000  92.28125 117.225806  46.1250  27.35484  29.16129
#[10,]  37.77143  43.37931  90.43750  51.45161  25.71875 120.22581 111.6562 126.81250 123.193548  46.0625  84.74194  97.53125
```

How might I improve the performance?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, if the date range is, say, 2019-01-11  2019-02-13, you want to count that as 21 days in January and 13 days in February. Therefore, the value of 179 gets divided up as 21/34 * 179 allocated to January and 13/34 * 179 allocated to February?

Comment: @eipi10 Yeah that's exactly right. The way I wrote it was to also use weights of new February days from another set of columns, including a February of a different year. But the math is as you say

Comment: The example solution doesn't work for me as is; what package is `month` function coming from, lubridate? Where is `month_cols` defined? Can you share what `output` looks like?

Comment: Apologies, fixing now. month appears to be a `data.table` function that I'm using.

Comment: It also is possible my code is incorrectly double counting days...
`sum(testdata[1,values])` and `sum(output[1,])` should probably be nearly identical assuming the 12 reads aren't over 365 days of data...

Comment: How do you want to deal with edge cases like a period going from Jan 31 to Mar 2? Is the general idea that you want to spread value across the calendar days, so that should be 1 Jan,  28 or 29 in Feb depending on leapness, and 2 March?

Comment: @JonSpring yes that would be the result. I'm wondering if the next date start being March 2 means I should subtract 1 from end dates but that's not really relevant for performance speed XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here ie a `data.table` + `lubridate` approach.

My output differs from your desired output. but I'm not sure which one is right ;-)

```
library( data.table )
library(lubridate)
#make data.table
setDT( testdata )
#insert row_id
testdata[, row_id := .I ]
#melt
dt <- melt( testdata, 
            id.vars = "row_id",
            measure.vars = patterns( 
              Start_Date = "^Start", 
              End_Date = "^End", 
              Value = "^Value" ) )
#drop the meaningless variable
dt[, variable := NULL ]
#Calculate daily value
dt[, value_day := Value / as.numeric( difftime( End_Date,  Start_Date, units = "days") ) ]
#create a table per day over the entire period
dt.days <- data.table( date = seq( min( dt$Start_Date, na.rm = TRUE ), 
                                   max( dt$End_Date, na.rm = TRUE ), 
                                   by = "1 days" ) )
#left join
answer <- dt[ dt.days, on = .(Start_Date <= date, End_Date >= date ), mult = "all", allow.cartesian = TRUE ]
#and summarise by monthly period
dcast(
  answer[, 
         .(month.total = sum( value_day ) ), 
         by = .(row_id, month = sprintf( "%02d", lubridate::month( Start_Date ) ) ) ],
  row_id ~ month )
```

**output**

```
#    row_id        01        02        03        04        05        06        07        08         09        10        11        12
# 1:      1 115.40909 168.01515 130.37946  47.84375  28.72581  78.94456 131.56250  98.65323  98.550777 142.37037 114.04421  34.49194
# 2:      2 135.46875  55.68750        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA        NA        NA  61.50000
# 3:      3  85.80844  61.62857  96.01290 103.51613  48.06810  45.21408  85.07879  22.26667 103.366667 196.43750  80.62500 149.92045
# 4:      4  49.09028  33.21481  32.18387 131.71635 141.57241  53.88889 138.18287  27.51420  52.765152 136.45833 116.20833 159.31250
# 5:      5 124.28125 167.18966 145.70474 102.10985 102.34897 117.64627  96.46305 113.35714 120.302381 167.90000 202.06667 107.49537
# 6:      6  99.73750  56.45455  58.86532 131.43098 135.22944 131.92857 156.06061 100.60065   9.714286  31.29032  97.69077 143.41494
# 7:      7  69.83699 119.09740  70.61364  71.99413 108.17419 163.96667 195.71717 120.27778  38.170833 131.30000 127.80000 105.21839
# 8:      8  66.60000 131.43750 132.48661  39.21429 114.31111 131.80208 149.83266 135.40601 149.424569 219.95833 186.07407  81.61905
# 9:      9  39.41838 105.23569  81.37566 200.00000  96.94355  47.00587 115.61039 101.48333 119.333333  44.72727  26.52456  30.92325
# 10:     10  42.05603  40.73637  93.35484  52.61958  27.69195 113.56970 108.27273 131.72121 134.688889  52.06452  82.30242  97.53125
```

Comment: Thanks for the data.table approach - need to familiarize myself a bit with these functions `pattern` and `"^"`. I've updated my Question with some text above the output describing what I was trying to do. Let me know if that clarifies at all.

Comment: the `^` is for a regex.. tale a look at `?data.table::melt` for the use of `patterns()` here *scroll down).  Is is necessairy to keep the data in the output format you described?

Comment: I updated the answer to something that resembles your desired output.. values differ though.. maybe you can figure out why..

Comment: I’ll give this a test today - i’m guessing it might be because (if i’m reading right) joining is done as if end dates are inclusive (like start dates are) when Im treating them as exclusive. Everyone is getting different results than me so starting to think i need to recheck my math lol

Comment: If you want to exclude the End_Date, use `End_Date > date` in the left join above..

Answer (score 1):

I expect it will be faster to reshape the data into long format, then perform some vectorized calculations, and then reshape the data back to final form, even though the reshaping steps will add a little overhead.

Here's a `tidyverse` approach using `fuzzyjoin` to add month-end breaks into each period, as applicable. This way should adapt flexibly to periods that exist across 1, 2, 3, or more months.

First, here's a reshaping of the data into long form.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Helper function to gather all columns whose names start with "header"
extract_cols <- function(header, col_name) {
  testdata %>%
  select(starts_with(header)) %>%
  mutate(meter_num = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-meter_num, 
               names_to = "period", names_pattern = paste0(header, "(.*)"), 
               values_to = col_name)
}

# Using the helper function, make one long table, with a row for each meter-period.
testdate_long <- extract_cols("Start_Date_", "Start") %>%
                   left_join(extract_cols("End_Date_", "End")) %>%
                   left_join(extract_cols("Value_", "Val")) %>%
                   mutate(ttl_days = (End-Start)/ddays(1))
```

It now looks like this:

```
> testdate_long
# A tibble: 120 x 6
   meter_num period Start      End          Val ttl_days
       <int> <chr>  <date>     <date>     <int>    <dbl>
 1         1 01     2018-12-23 2019-01-24    82       32
 2         1 02     2019-01-24 2019-02-26   189       33
 3         1 03     2019-02-26 2019-03-25   106       27
 4         1 04     2019-03-25 2019-04-27   111       33
 5         1 05     2019-04-27 2019-05-27   192       30
 6         1 06     2019-05-27 2019-06-26   136       30
 7         1 07     2019-06-26 2019-07-27    21       31
 8         1 08     2019-07-27 2019-08-29    50       33
 9         1 09     2019-08-29 2019-09-25    66       27
10         1 10     2019-09-25 2019-10-28   178       33
# … with 110 more rows
```

Now, it would be useful to note all the month-ends that fall within each period. Most of the time, there will be one, but sometimes there will be none (End is same month as Start), and sometimes there will be two or more (e.g. Jan 31 to Mar 2, or a period that is longer than 1 month). One way to get that would be to use `fuzzyjoin` to add all the month-ends that fall between Start and End.

```
# Make a list of all the month end dates that might come into play
month_ends <- data.frame(
  month_ends = seq.Date(
    ceiling_date(min(testdate_long$Start, na.rm = T), "month"),
    ceiling_date(max(testdate_long$End, na.rm = T), "month"), by = "months") - 1)

# Add all the month-ends and calculate the length of all the date ranges, from Start to (if applicable) month-end to End:

testdate_full <- testdate_long %>%
  mutate(ttl_days = (End-Start)/ddays(1)) %>%
  fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(month_ends,
                             by = c("Start" = "month_ends",
                                    "End"   = "month_ends"),  
                             match_fun = list(`<`, `>`)) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(Start, End, month_ends),
               names_to = "type", values_to = "date") %>%
  arrange(meter_num, period, date) %>% 
  # Edited below to remove "group_by"
  mutate(mo = month(date),
         days = if_else(meter_num == lag(meter_num) & period == lag(period),
                    (date - lag(date))/ddays(1),
                    NA_real_)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(date), !is.na(days))
```

Then it's simple to get weighted values and spread them into the desired output format.

```
testdate_full %>%
  mutate(val_wtd = Val * days / ttl_days) %>%
  count(meter_num, mo, wt = val_wtd, name = "val_wtd") %>%
  spread(mo, val_wtd)
```

(I see this produces different values than your output, I'll come back to check if I missed something. In any case I hope this brings you closer to a more performant solution.)
Here's a bit of checking. Starting with the first row of `testdata`, there seem to be two periods which occur partly in January.

```
> testdata[1, c(1:6)]
  Start_Date_01 End_Date_01 Value_01 Start_Date_02 End_Date_02 Value_02
1    2018-12-23  2019-01-24       82    2019-01-24  2019-02-26      189
```

The first period has 24 (75%) of its 32 days in January. 0.75 x 82 = 61.5

The 2nd period has 7 (21.21%) of its 33 days in January. 0.21 x 189 = 40.1

So I'd expect to see 101.6 here, which corresponds with the result produced here.

Comment: Thanks for this tidyverse approach - The long file becomes +4.7 million rows now - I think my computer might have crashed but will let you know when/if my time check finishes up. Now that it's not a looped approach, harder to see if it's ticking away or if I've ruined R

Comment: Yeah unfortunately my computer crashes when applying this logic. An approach might be for me to chunk my data up into more bite size chunks (~50k rows) and then run...

Comment: I think the group_at step was a bottleneck. It works with bigger data (eg with your fake data up to 20k rows, the most I could get) now by removing that.

Answer (score 1):

This way is very fast but assumes a few things about the data:

1. Each record in column `j` is about the same general month. Let's say January for example.
2. The month range in `j` is in the month before or after the general month. For January that means that December through February would be accounted for.

This uses [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) for the `year()` and `month()` functions.

```
library(data.table)
# vectors identifying the column positions 
starts <- grep('Start', names(testdata))
ends <- grep('End', names(testdata))
values <- grep('Value', names(testdata))

# calculating how many days are in each period and the value per day
days_per_period <- do.call(cbind, (lapply(testdata[ends] - testdata[starts] + 1, as.numeric)))
val_per_day <- as.matrix(testdata[values]) / days_per_period

# seq the dates based on the minimum and maximum 
min_date <- as.Date(min(unlist(testdata[starts], use.names = F), na.rm = T),  origin ="1970-01-01")
max_date <- as.Date(max(unlist(testdata[ends], use.names = F), na.rm = T),  origin ="1970-01-01")

start_months <- seq.Date(as.Date(paste(year(min_date), month(min_date), '1', sep = '/')),
                         as.Date(paste(year(max_date), month(max_date), '1', sep = '/')),
                         by = 'month')

# calculates the days for each month
## WARNING
## Assumes that for any column j that the only possible months would be
## the months prior and after the "current" month
lag_mon <- mapply(function(met_start, month_start) pmax(month_start - met_start - 1 , 0), testdata[starts], start_months[2:13])
lead_mon <- mapply(function(met_end, month_end) pmax(met_end - (month_end-1) , 0), testdata[ends], start_months[3:14])
cur_mon <- days_per_period - lag_mon - lead_mon 

lag_mon_val <- cbind(lag_mon * val_per_day, 0, 0)
cur_mon_val <- cbind(0, cur_mon * val_per_day, 0)
lead_mon_val <- cbind(0, 0, lead_mon * val_per_day)

# makes an array to deal with NAs. Otherwise, this would be
# simply lag_mon_val + cur_mon_val + lead_mon_val
arrs <- array(c(lag_mon_val, cur_mon_val, lead_mon_val),
              dim = c(dim(lag_mon_val)[1], dim(lag_mon_val)[2], 3),
              dimnames = list(NULL, as.character(start_months), c('lag', 'cur', 'lead')))

apply(arrs, 2, rowSums, na.rm = T)
```

Results: (7 columns truncated):

```
     2018-12-01 2019-01-01 2019-02-01 2019-03-01 2019-04-01 2019-05-01 2019-06-01
 [1,]   0.000000 110.558824  162.98663  126.31661   46.28945   27.84848   76.54545
 [2,]  54.666667 133.878788   56.45455    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000
 [3,]   0.000000  64.241379   59.62959   93.00403   99.87500   45.09375   42.45037
 [4,]   4.545455  47.883117   32.82949   27.61694  126.42500  141.24839   47.02304
 [5,]   0.000000 102.515152  161.91818  141.02121   99.04545   99.25000  113.91667
 [6,]   0.000000  48.424242   54.75223   56.85924  127.14076  131.03043  127.67189
 [7,]   0.000000  42.882353  115.04868   68.36308   69.76838  104.71169  159.04934
 [8,]   0.000000  55.741935  127.34897  128.35737   37.87430  110.24885  127.36797
 [9,]   3.000000  35.058824  104.36975   73.05419  195.68966   97.64009   41.92279
[10,]   0.000000   7.666667   39.45833   90.43750   50.93750   26.79032  110.20968
```

Comment: Thanks for supplying an answer - will look through jt today. I will say that columns j are actually reverse sequential (Sep 2019ish to Aug 2018ish) but not starting on the same month for all rows. Will take a look at this soon

Comment: Is the second part of the logic true? That is, the month range is always within 3 consecutive months?

Comment: The range for any j is dynamic and spans roughly 33 days - have yet to test this code

Comment: Thanks. And I am not trying to be impatient - just figuring out how to try to modify

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that uses the "IRanges" package to perform computations with (here date) intervals.

First, separate the data for convenience:

```
col_starts = testdata[grep("^Start_Date", names(testdata))]
col_ends = testdata[grep("^End_Date", names(testdata))]
col_values = testdata[grep("^Value", names(testdata))]
```

Here it is clear that "testdata" contains `length(col_starts)` (= 12) date intervals for each record (row) defined as [col_starts, col_ends]. Next, we need to find the intervals of the calendar months that span the time period ot "testdata":

```
# Find starting month
start_date = as.POSIXlt(do.call(min, c(na.rm = TRUE, col_starts)))
start_date$mday = 1L
start_date = as.Date(start_date)

# Find ending month (+ 1)
end_date = as.POSIXlt(do.call(max, c(na.rm = TRUE, col_ends)))
end_date$mon = end_date$mon + 1L
end_date$mday = 1L
end_date = as.Date(end_date)

# Create a series of months between first and last
month_series = seq(start_date, end_date, by = "1 month")

# create the intervals of existing months
month_starts = head(month_series, -1)
month_ends = tail(month_series, -1) - 1
```

By now we have the [month_starts, month_ends] intervals which overlap with the intervals defined in "testdata". These intervals defined as an "IRanges" object:

```
library(IRanges)
month_ints = IRanges(as.numeric(month_starts), as.numeric(month_ends))
```

Now we need to loop over the (`length(col_starts)`) successive intervals of "testdata" and  spread their values according to their overlaps with "month_ints". First allocate the output that'll hold the values for each month which will be updated while passing through all the intervals:

```
output = matrix(0, nrow = nrow(col_starts), ncol = length(month_series), 
                dimnames = list(c(), as.character(month_series)))
```

And now iterate through all intervals of "testdata":

```
for(j in 1:ncol(col_starts)) {

    # prepare (remove "date" attribute and handle NAs) for IRanges
    s = as.numeric(col_starts[, j])
    e = as.numeric(col_ends[, j] - 1)  # '- 1' to exclude ending day
    hasNA = !complete.cases(s, e)
    s[hasNA] = 0L
    e[hasNA] = 0L

    # an IRanges object containing current period intervals for all rows
    current_ints = IRanges(s, e)

    # average the interval's value across its days
    value_by_day = col_values[, j] / width(current_ints)

    # count amount of overlap between current (j) intervals and month intervals
    overlaps = findOverlaps(current_ints, month_ints)
    overlaps_width = width(pintersect(current_ints[from(overlaps)], month_ints[to(overlaps)]))

    # update "output"
    index = cbind(from(overlaps), to(overlaps))
    output[index] = output[index] + (value_by_day[from(overlaps)] * overlaps_width)
}
```

"output" holds the values per month from the starting to the ending date of "testdata". To efficiently aggregate values per month regardless of year:

```
which_month = as.numeric(format(as.Date(colnames(output)), "%m"))
monthly_values = matrix(0L, nrow = nrow(output), ncol = max(which_month), 
                        dimnames = list(NULL, 1:max(which_month)))
for(j in 1:ncol(output)) 
    monthly_values[, which_month[j]] =  monthly_values[, which_month[j]] + output[, j]
```

The final output:

```
#> round(monthly_values, 1)
#          1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
# [1,] 115.2 162.6 124.3  46.1  27.4  78.5 126.8  95.4  95.6 139.0 109.0  31.3
# [2,] 130.3  53.2   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  61.5
# [3,]  81.0  59.2  93.9 100.4  43.3  43.9  82.4  21.7 100.2 190.2  80.6 147.2
# [4,]  47.5  32.0  31.8 127.6 136.3  53.2 132.3  26.7  51.7 132.1 112.5 154.4
# [5,] 122.6 161.0 140.5  98.3  99.8 113.3  93.9 109.6 117.0 163.4 196.3 100.5
# [6,]  97.0  53.5  58.1 127.5 130.7 128.3 151.1  95.9   9.5  30.8  95.9 137.8
# [7,]  66.6 117.5  65.7  70.5 105.5 160.3 189.8 114.1  35.2 130.8 122.3 101.8
# [8,]  65.3 127.8 127.0  37.1 113.9 125.0 147.2 129.1 146.8 213.8 178.7  76.3
# [9,]  38.9 101.4  79.9 192.9  92.5  46.7 111.5  99.3 114.3  43.1  25.7  29.8
#[10,]  39.2  40.4  91.6  49.2  26.8 112.7 103.6 129.0 129.6  48.2  81.6  94.1
```

And a check:

```
#> all(rowSums(monthly_values) == rowSums(col_values, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] TRUE
```